# How do I set the time of a datetime column in python pandas based on a string column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame containing a DateTime column with dates but without time `['date_from']`. I have the time in column `['Time']` (string). How can I add only the time to the already existing DateTime column?

I tried:

```
df['date_from'].dt.time = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H%M').dt.time
```

Comment: `column with dates but without time` like? Can you show an example

Comment: e.g. 2018-01-01 00:00:00 as datetime column and another column with strings 0000, 0500, 0610, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add to `datetime` column:

```
#convert to string and if necessary add zero for 4 values
s = df['Time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df['date_from'] += pd.to_timedelta(s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:] + ':00')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_from':pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3),
                   'Time':[1501,112, 2012]})

print (df)    
   Time  date_from
0  1501 2015-01-01
1  0112 2015-01-02
2  2012 2015-01-03

s = df['Time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)
df['date_from'] += pd.to_timedelta(s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:] + ':00')
print (df)
   Time           date_from
0  1501 2015-01-01 15:01:00
1  0112 2015-01-02 01:12:00
2  2012 2015-01-03 20:12:00
```

Comment: Even I thought exactly same. This might work. Curious what actual data looks like.

Comment: I think data looks like `%H%M` ;)

Comment: Yeah slicing them and adding a  timedelta. Yes I got you.

Comment: Thanks, works as described. Time column was already a string in 4 values so I could skip that step.